# Flutter - AnimatedBuilder , animation/widget bugs out when loading in for first time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-web

when I load the builder for the first time , all of my cards are the same size for a second before jumping to the correct sizes and proportions ,does anyone know how I can adjust this so that they are in the right sizes from the get go?

Strangely enough when I replace my Padding & Card widget with just a container full of the images, it seems to spawn in the correct sizes , however I need them to be cards for my later layout.

(I also plan on throwing it all into a widget class instead of putting all this code in my main and rather just returning a CustomScroller.)

Please check the following Gifs:

[Gif Of Animation Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Qpy.gif)
[Gif of Animation working fine when just container is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jx2O.gif)

Any help fixing the initial loading would be wildly appreciated! :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:blink/widget/customScroller.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController pageController;

  List<String> images = [
    "https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/big-one.jpg",
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXRfe-GzBFRQzv8udHMCshqQGAj2JD5SGsR7CoyWP_HqFapJCYSA&s",
    "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/live/976_549/images/live/p0/7w/b9/p07wb9xk.jpg",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501785888041-af3ef285b470?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: 0.77);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
            itemCount: images.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,position){
            return customScroller(position);
            }),);
  }

  customScroller(int index) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: pageController,
      builder: (context, widget) {
        double val = 1;

        if(pageController.position.haveDimensions){
          val = pageController.page - index;
        val = 1 - (val.abs()*0.3).clamp(0.0,1.0);}

        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: Curves.easeInOut.transform(val) *300,
              width: Curves.easeInOut.transform(val) *400,
            child: widget,
          ),
        );
      },
//      child: Container(
//        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
//        child: Image.network(images[index],fit:BoxFit.cover),
//      ),
// When I use the above code as the child instead of the padding with the card in it seems to spawn correctly
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 15),
          child: Container(
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.white70,
              elevation: 9,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(0.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(0.0),
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: new Image.network(
                            images[index],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that the AnimatedBuilder build method runs only if there is some animation. Not at the very beginning. So this is why the size changes if you are scrolling and not before.

Your child widget is not wrapped with a transformer widget (or sized box) so it stays the same for all indexes (at the beginnen - the builder has not run yet). In my example I wrapped the child also with a SizedBox and i gave val some initial value.

Working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController pageController;

  List<String> images = [
    "https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/big-one.jpg",
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXRfe-GzBFRQzv8udHMCshqQGAj2JD5SGsR7CoyWP_HqFapJCYSA&s",
    "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/live/976_549/images/live/p0/7w/b9/p07wb9xk.jpg",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501785888041-af3ef285b470?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: 0.77);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: images.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return customScroller(position);
          }),
    );
  }

  customScroller(int index) {
    Widget child = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 15),
      child: Container(
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white70,
          elevation: 9,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(0.0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(0.0),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      child: new Image.network(
                        images[index],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    double val = (index == 1)?1:0.7;

    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: pageController,
        builder: (context, widget) {
          if (pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
            val = pageController.page - index;
            val = 1 - (val.abs() * 0.3).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
          }
          print("val: $val; index: $index");
          return _getTransformedSizedBox(val, widget);
        },
//      child: Container(
//        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
//        child: Image.network(images[index],fit:BoxFit.cover),
//      ),
// When I use the above code as the child instead of the padding with the card in it seems to spawn correctly
        child: _getTransformedSizedBox(val, child));
  }

  _getTransformedSizedBox(double val, Widget widget) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: Curves.easeInOut.transform(val) * 300,
        width: Curves.easeInOut.transform(val) * 400,
        child: widget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```