# Flutter transform.rotate not rotating list items in animated builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I followed this tutorial which explores creating a ui for a movie app

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgSLd2lH1FM&feature=youtu.be

While most of the design I was able to recreate and add my own settings to,I face a problem in the Poster display side of the tutorial, Mainly that in the builder, It is specified that the pages to the right and left of the one in focus are inclined at 15 degrees.:
[The poster view should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmT0f.png)

The transform.rotate part works, but only after the user starts scrolling horizontally in the poster list.
before the scroll it looks like this:
[What the carousel looks like before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bsCE.png)

This happens both in the simulator and a real device. Also I tried using transform.translate to see if that gives the same problem but it does not.

Below is a code snippet of the Animated builder.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: kDefaultPadding / 2, horizontal: 0),
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 0.85,
    child: PageView.builder(
      itemCount: movies.length,
      controller: _pageController // declared PageController type in class//,
      onPageChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          // initialPage was initialised with value 1
          initialPage = value;
        });
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildMovieCard(index),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

The animatedBuilder calling function is below.

```
 Widget buildMovieCard(int index) => AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _pageController,
  builder: (context, child) {
    double value = 0;
    if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
      value = index - _pageController.page;
      //0.038 since it time pi gives 7 so 7 rotaitons
       value = (value * 0.038).clamp(-1, 1);
    }
    return  Transform.rotate(
      child: MovieCard(movie: movies[index]),
      angle: math.pi * value,
    );
    
  });
```

(Sorry if the information above is Convoluted.. )
Do tell me if there are any errors in the way I have framed this question

EDIT: I tried searching a bit more, and found a similar question.
it seems that animations won't be executed until an animation plays for an animated builder.
I dont have too much experience in animated builder stuff so if I find something ill add it
[Here is the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939423/flutter-animatedbuilder-animation-widget-bugs-out-when-loading-in-for-first)

I Tried using a SingleTickerProvider and an animation controller with .repeat() to continuously run the animatedBuilder. The rotation now does appear automatically, but it takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `_pageController.page` set correctly at the start?

What happens if you print `value` inside your if:

```
if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
  ...
  print(value);
}
```

(sorry I don't have the reputation to comment directly on the question on this account)

Comment: I initialised   _pageController as  
        PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, initialPage: initialPage); in the initState function

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand the code, but according to the description you might try to simulate a scroll or see what exactly the scroll affects, and try to implement it.
Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I dont know exactly how to "simulate" a scroll. the scroll function works, and I can move about in the list , if that is what you are asking.